# Can anyone identify this please?

Tags: entomology

I found this in a toilet in the UK. Any ideas what it is please?
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A Flat-Backed Millipede.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydesmus_angustus)

The [Woodland Trust](https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/trees-woods-and-wildlife/animals/centipedes-and-millipedes/flat-backed-millipede/) has an article that's much more informative than the Wikipedia page:

[image: Brown, flat-backed millipede]

<sup>Via Wikipedia, [CC By-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en), Ratingen, Germany.</sup>

They're:

> This species has a long, flat, segmented body with a large number of
> legs. It is orangey-brown in colour and measures around 2cm in length.

Herbivores, normally found in woodland where they live under leaf-litter.

Widespread throughout the UK.